# gnu make Archive Members as Targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a problem with GNU make when using [Archive Members as Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Archive-Members.html#Archive-Members). The problem is that on some machines (e.g. running MacOS, Solaris) it works fine, i.e. builds the library and the next `make` gives `Nothing to be done for 'all'`.

But not on the Linux boxes there make always rebuild everything. On all machines I am using GNU Make.

Here the example with one source file `foo.c` and the `Makefile`

foo.c

```
void foo() {}
```

Makefile

```
all: libfoo.a

libfoo.a(%.o) : %.o
        $(AR) cr $@ $^

libfoo.a: libfoo.a(foo.o)
        ranlib libfoo.a
```

Can anyone confirm that? (or tell me what obvious stupid mistake I have done ...?)

Run on Solaris

```
theon$ make
gcc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
ar cr libfoo foo.o
ranlib libfoo
rm foo.o
theon$ make
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

Run on Linux

```
acker$ make
gcc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
ar cr libfoo foo.o
ranlib libfoo
rm foo.o
acker$ make
gcc    -c -o foo.o foo.c
ar cr libfoo foo.o
ranlib libfoo
rm foo.o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's not you, it's that your GNU/Linux distribution is stupid and has set "deterministic mode" as the default behavior of `ar`.  This is a configure-time option for the `ar` program, to determine whether it defaults to "deterministic" or "non-deterministic" (the historical and correct default behavior for `ar`).  Some distributions made the ridiculous decision to set this configuration option in their version of `ar`, and change the default behavior.

This breaks `make` (and any other tool that needs to know the timestamps of objects).

If this is the problem, you can change your invocation of `ar` to add the `U` option to turn deterministic mode off again:

```
ARFLAGS = crU
```

Unfortunately it's likely that the `ar` commands on non-GNU systems won't understand this option so you'll need to find a way to add it only for the ones using GNU binutils.

You should also feel free to complain to your GNU/Linux distribution about this.

Comment: Wow, you are awesome. Using `ARFLAGS = crU` fixed the problem. But sure, I will complain! And by the way I am a big fan of your blog. Your articles like Auto-Dependency Generation are game changer.